# My IP isn't listed on my D-link routers active clients?

Tags: networking, ip

I'm having some issues trying to reserv an IP from my D-link DIR-825 router.

I have set up a static IP on my computer: 192.167.0.10. But if i view the clients on my network that ip doesn't show up! That's my problem. Any ideas why?

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Any clues what's going on? I really want this sorted out.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

// qwerty

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that after i tried to reserve it now. I changed it to 110 instead of 10 at the end. I think i got it working now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your router is showing you the "number of dynamic DHCP clients". You have configured your computer to **not** be a dynamic DHCP client, so it is not showing in the list.

If you want a "static" IP address, you should find a way onto the "DHCP reservations list". This is usually done by giving the router the MAC address of your computer's network interface and choosing which IP address you want.

[From D-Link's website](http://www.dlink.com/support/faqDetail/?prod_id=2472&print=1):

> Q: How do I utilize DHCP reservation in my DIR series router?
>
> A: DHCP Reservation is used to assign a specific IP address to a specific MAC address on the LAN.
>
> To do so, use the following steps:
>
> 1. Open a web browser and type the IP address of the DIR series router into the address bar (default is http://192.168.0.1).
> 2. The default username is admin (all lower case) and the default password is blank (leave empty) unless one has been assign. Click on OK.
> 3. Click on the Setup tab at the top and then click on Network Settings on the left-hand side.
> 4. Scroll down to Add DHCP Reservation.
> 5. Input a desired name and address. Click the Copy Your PC’s MAC Address button if you want to reserve for the computer in use. You may click on the Reserve link if available to the client you are reserving the IP address.
>
>    Note: If the Reservation address you’re creating is not for the machine that you are working from or not listed, you’ll need to obtain the MAC address of that machine.
> 6. Click on the Save button then on Save Settings to apply your new settings.

Comment: I cannot believe i missed that! Thank you William, i appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Reserved IP is set aside by the DHCP and will always be assigned to the associated MAC address. A static IP is assigned on the host.

I can see on [the D-Link DIR-825 router emulator](http://support.dlink.com/emulators/dir825/) that your router supports adding reserved DHCP entries. Log into your router, click Setup, then Network Settings, which should bring you to a page that looks like [this](http://support.dlink.com/emulators/dir825/113NA/Basic_Network.html). Scroll down to the "Add DHCP Reservation" section, enter your computer's MAC address and the IP you would like to reserve for it and hit save. Now set your computer to use DHCP.

Now you should see your computer under the heading "Dynamic DHCP Clients". Note that this doesn't accurately represent which clients are using the network, just which ones have asked the DHCP server for an IP within the expiry time.

You might consider looking at alternatives for your router, such as [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) or [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/).