# D-link DIR600 DHCP clients list

Tags: router, dhcp

I have a DIR-600 Wi-fi router and would like to know, where can I find DHCP clients list. I found only `NAPT Active Sessions` menu entry, which contains private IP addresses and TCP / UDP sessions. It isn't contains computer names.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Where can I find DHCP clients list?

Log in to your router and go to the "Network Settings" page.

[image]

Source [D-Link DIR-600 User Manual](http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Consumer_Products/DIR/DIR%20600/Manual/DIR_600_revb5_man_en_Manual.pdf)

Comment: Yes, that is ok, but this list is empty. I have connected clients.

Comment: Try resetting your router. You can also try using another browser. There have been reports that trying another browser will dislay the list correctly.

Comment: You may also have to enable "DHCP Reservation". See this answer [My IP isn't listed on my D-link routers active clients?](http://superuser.com/a/285892)

Comment: Are they wireless clients? Have you checked the "Wireless" > "Status" page?

Comment: "Number Of Wireless Clients: 0"